# SQL - all patients who had only dental visits in 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a T-SQL query that's giving me the most recent office visit in 2010 that wasn't a dental visit. The relevant part of the query is:

```
AND pv.PatientVisitId IN (                
    SELECT Max(pv1.PatientVisitID)            
        FROM PatientVisit pv1        
            JOIN DoctorFacility df1 ON pv1.FacilityID = df1.DoctorFacilityID
            JOIN PatientVisitResource pvr1 ON pv1.PatientVisitId = pvr1.PatientVisitId
                JOIN DoctorFacility dfr ON pvr1.ResourceId = dfr.DoctorFacilityId
        WHERE pv1.PatientProfileID = pp.PatientProfileID        
            AND pv1.Visit < '2011-01-01'    
            AND df1.ListName NOT LIKE '%Dental%'    
    )
```

Now, I want to flip that around to get the most recent office visit for the patients who *only* had dental appointments. I keep hitting the wall here, though. Can anyone bust me through to the other side? :-)

Comment: If you use this snippet and remove the word Not (from not like dental) you will get dental appointments (presumably). 

Then re-use this query to get you a list of people that had non dental appointments. Left outer Join the two tables where the query above is null.

Comment: added the sql-server-2000 tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clue is to use where not exists

```
AND pv.PatientVisitId IN (                
    SELECT Max(pv1.PatientVisitID)            
        FROM PatientVisit pv1        
            JOIN DoctorFacility df1 ON pv1.FacilityID = df1.DoctorFacilityID
            JOIN PatientVisitResource pvr1 ON pv1.PatientVisitId = pvr1.PatientVisitId
                JOIN DoctorFacility dfr ON pvr1.ResourceId = dfr.DoctorFacilityId
        WHERE pv1.PatientProfileID = pp.PatientProfileID        
            AND pv1.Visit < '2011-01-01'    
            AND df1.ListName LIKE '%Dental%'    
    ) 
and not exists ( Select 1 from   PatientVisit pv1        
            JOIN DoctorFacility df1 ON pv1.FacilityID = df1.DoctorFacilityID
            JOIN PatientVisitResource pvr1 ON pv1.PatientVisitId = pvr1.PatientVisitId
                JOIN DoctorFacility dfr ON pvr1.ResourceId = dfr.DoctorFacilityId
        WHERE pv1.PatientProfileID = pp.PatientProfileID        
            AND pv1.Visit < '2011-01-01'    
            AND df1.ListName NOT LIKE '%Dental%'    
    )
```

Comment: By George, I think you've got it! :-) I need to check this a bit more, but the numbers look reasonable at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

probably numerous was to do this, but the first way that pops into my head is to compare the count(1) of patientvisit to the count(1) of patientvisit where df1.listname like '%Dental%', if those are equal, then they've only been to the dentist.

Comment: I couldn't quite get this to work before bernd_k posted his solution, but it might have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use `EXCEPT` to exclude a group of records from another query.

So basically write your larger query (show me ALL the patients that had a visit this year!), then...

```
...
EXCEPT
SELECT pv1.PatientVisitID        
        FROM PatientVisit pv1        
            JOIN DoctorFacility df1 ON pv1.FacilityID = df1.DoctorFacilityID
            JOIN PatientVisitResource pvr1 ON pv1.PatientVisitId = pvr1.PatientVisitId
                JOIN DoctorFacility dfr ON pvr1.ResourceId = dfr.DoctorFacilityId
        WHERE pv1.PatientProfileID = pp.PatientProfileID        
            AND pv1.Visit < '2011-01-01'    
            AND df1.ListName NOT LIKE '%Dental%'
```

Something to bear in mind with this is you need to have the **same columns in both queries** (there can be SOME differences, but for our purposes make sure both the first `SELECT` and the `EXCEPT` query return the same fields).

Comment: I'm working on getting 2005 for a reporting server, but for the moment, I'm stuck with 2000. This looks like it could be useful at some point in the future, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
AND pv.PatientVisitId IN (              
  SELECT MAX(pv1.PatientVisitID) 
  FROM PatientVisit pv1                
    JOIN DoctorFacility df1 ON pv1.FacilityID = df1.DoctorFacilityID        
    JOIN PatientVisitResource pvr1 ON pv1.PatientVisitId = pvr1.PatientVisitId        
    JOIN DoctorFacility dfr ON pvr1.ResourceId = dfr.DoctorFacilityId       
  WHERE pv1.PatientProfileID = pp.PatientProfileID                
    AND pv1.Visit < '2011-01-01'            
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN df1.ListName LIKE '%Dental%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
)
```

Comment: Same problem -- this doesn't exclude patients who've had both medical and dental visits.

Comment: Try this...I changed the top 1 to a max and added the having clause.